# Nullstellensatz for maximal left ideals of quantum plane

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry, noncommutative-rings

Let $R=\mathbb{C}\langle x,y\rangle/\langle xy=qyx\rangle$ be the quantum plane algebra. Does some sort of Nullstellensatz holds for the maximal left ideals of $R$? By this we mean all maximal left ideals of $R$ are of the form $R(x-a)+R(y-b)$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Do you care whether q is a root of unity or not? The answer almost certainly changes depending on this.